# Create a button which duplicate elements of an array

Tags: javascript, haml

Hello everybody I'm new in javascript. I want to create a button which duplicate elements in an array. I try this :

```
   %a.btn.btn-success#addd{ :href => "#", :onclick => "duplicate(this.parentNode.parentNode)" }

       :javascript
       document.getElementById('addd').click = duplicate;

       var i = 0;
       var original = document.getElementById('inf_finding.id');

       function duplicate(original) {
         var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
         clone.id = "inf_finding.id" + ++i;
         original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
       }
```

But I refresh it, the element that I add is not in the page anymore.Can you help me to resolve this please ? 
Here are the screenshots :

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Us3.png)

[It add properly the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaDDe.png)

[But when I refresh the page, the element disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVAAc.png)

Comment: Of course, when you reload the page, everything is reset. What did you expect :) You have to implement some kind of persistence, the easiest being probably the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) that can store strings and is unaffected by page refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only makes changes within the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) of the current webpage. When the page is refreshed, the DOM is regenerated from the HTML sent by the server and so your changes are lost.

In order to make persistent changes, you need to save data either on the *server* (using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)) or in the *browser* using [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), etc.